# Problems about 'left join' in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have two tables：

table A：         table B:

```
id m1             id  m2
------            -------
1  a              1   a
2  b              2   c
3                 3   d
```

when I execute the sql:

```
select A.*,B.id as mid from A left join B on A.m1 = b.m2
```

I want to get the result:

```
id   m1   mid
--------------
1    a   1
2    b   
3
```

but I get:

```
  id   m1   mid
    --------------
    1    a   1
    2    b
```

Does anyone have idea how to fix this?

Comment: Is the `m1` value of `third` row empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm getting the correct results in this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/986f44/1).

```
| ID |     M1 |    MID |
|----|--------|--------|
|  1 |      a |      1 |
|  2 |      b | (null) |
|  3 | (null) | (null) |
```

It will also work for empty strings. The resulting behaviour you're mentioning goes against the left join.

Comment: yes,you're right,but in my project,it doesn't work.thank you for you answer.

Answer (score 0):

NULL comparison results in unknown so you might want to replace NULL with something in JOIN condition.

Answer (score 0):

I've updated Mosty Mostacho's fiddle (I'm not high enough rep to reply to answers) so that is uses empty strings instead of NULLs
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/48d78/5

```
| ID |     M1 |    MID |
|----|--------|--------|
|  1 |      a |      1 |
|  2 |      b |        |
|  3 |        |        |
```